# Take defined values and using them in a string method Java

Tags: java, string, methods, setter, getter

Hello everyone I am having a issue with a method that I am trying to create. My method is supposed to take the month, day, and year that are previously defined in the class, and then split them up with "/" marks. So if the values for month, day, year in that order were 1, 2, 14 it would print out as 1/2/14 (I am using a separate class to test if it works). So far I have this for my method:

```
public String DateTest(){
    DateTest = month + day + year;
    return DateTest;
}
```

with public String DateTest; being defined above it with the rest of the values. How can I create a method that returns the three integer values with "/"s dividing them (I am not sure on how to get the "/"s in there)?

Here is the code where I would be initializing the variables:

```
public class Date {
public int month;
public int day;
public int year;
public String DateTest;

public void setMonth(int month){
    this.month = month;
}
public int getMonth(){
    return month;
}

public void setDay(int day){
    this.day = day;
}
public int getDay(){
    return day;
}

public void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
}
public int getYear(){
    return year;
}
```

Comment: give it try, read more about java string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the desired `String` by concatenating the desired characters in form of `String`, then return the value:

```
public String yourDateTestWithSlashes() {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
               //^-----^ <-- this does the "magic"
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had already tried that, but I will try it again just in case.

Comment: Tried that but when I test it all I get is "null".

Comment: Are you sure you had defined their values?

Comment: Yes and it is still printing out as "null".

Comment: @Fyree that means some of the variables in the middle has a `null` value. Make sure you initialize your variables properly.

Comment: Even when I initialize them (like this: public int month = 2;) with values it still gives me null.

Comment: Well then, seems like you're not initializing `DateTest` field , so if you try to print it you will get a null value

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, I just made public String DateTest = month + "/" + day + "/" + year. Thank you for the help!